# How should I return multiple variables in a function (for best practices)?

Tags: php, micro-optimization

Just curious to know what the best practice would be for something like this:

A function, that returns multiple variables - how should one return these variables?

like this (globalizing):

```
function myfun(){

global $var1,$var2,$var3;

$var1="foo";
$var2="foo";
$var3="foo";

}//end of function
```

or like this (returning an array):

```
function myfun(){

$var1="foo";
$var2="foo";
$var3="foo";

$ret_var=array("var1"=>$var1,"var2"=>$var2,"var3"=>$var3);

return $ret_var;

}//end of function
```

I done a performance test, and it looks like using arrays is faster (after a few refreshes):

```
array took: 5.9999999999505E-6
global took: 2.0999999999938E-5
```

But I'm curious to know which method is the best practiced for a simple situation like this?

Comment: You mean arrays are faster, right?  5.9999999999505E-6 < 2.0999999999938E-5

Comment: Avoid globals as much as possible...

Comment: For the love of all that is holy do not use globals. They are a sad remnant from the bad old PHP4 days and have no place in new code

Comment: I don't think I've **ever** heard the term *"Best Practice"* in the same sentence as `global` ... Thanks for the laugh.

Comment: Don't test for tiny speed differences. Test to see which is easier to read and *maintain*. Imagine a person unfamiliar with the code having to understand it and extend it. In a year's time, that person could be you.

Comment: @navnav You could use references as proposed by Johannes Klauß in his answer. I'm quite sure that this will perform fast. If you find time to benchmark this solution too, I'd love to see a comparison of these three methods. If you do so, please answer this comment so I get noticed :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should absolutely return an array.  It is much clearer.  You can even use the [`list`](https://www.php.net/list) construct to simulate multiple return values a-la python:

```
function foon() {
   return array('one', 'two', 'three');
}
list($one, $two, $three) = foon();
```

Edit: in some cases an associative array is also quite appropriate.  I can't imagine the performance difference would merit this loss of clarity.

Answer (score 6):

Use references (if it makes sense) http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Example:

```
function myfun(&$var1, &$var2, &$var3)
{
    $var1="foo";
    $var2="foo";
    $var3="foo";
}
```

Or return an array.

**AND NEVER USE GLOBALS!** It is very bad design and not maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

The associative array option is better from a code maintenance standpoint since you're not mucking-up the global namespace.  Will also be easier for others to read your code.

Answer (score 2):

You could return an Array and use list to get the values, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

```php
function multiple() {
    return array('val1', 'anotherval');
}

list($var1, $var2) = multiple();

echo "$var1, $var2";
```

Works for me, I don't know how fast that is, but maybe it looks cleaner in your code.

Comment: well, I'm not that fast... I wanted to test my code first, and had to check how to do syntax highlighting -- next time, maybe...

Answer (score 2):

You can use class http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php.

```
class Vari {
    var $var1;
    var $var2;
    var $var3;
}

function myfun() {    
    $var = new Vari;
    $var->var1="foo";
    $var->var2="foo";
    $var->var3="foo";
    return $var;    
}

$v = myfun();
echo $v->var1;
/*foo*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Since this ranks so high on Google and the fact that it took me a while to find a clear answer myself to something so simple...

To give a complete answer and thoroughly clarify how to return multiple variables that you can actually use independently outside of your function:

```
  function  myFunction() {

      //your code that returns your results to variables below

     $var1 = 'message 1';
     $var2 = 'message 2';
     $var3 = 'message 3';

     // must put all variables inside an array to get them outside of function
     $return_array = ($var1, $var2, $var3);

     // return your array inside function
     return $return_array;
  }



 // call function (returns all variables in array)
 $get_results = myFunction();

 // call and assign individual variables outside of function
 $var1 = $get_results[0];
 $var2 = $get_results[1];
 $var3 = $get_results[2];



 // now you can use individual variables outside of function for example:

 echo $var2;   //will now output: message 2
 echo $var3;   //will now output: message 3
```

If you are using results from database query inside your function more than likely you will need to pass your connection variable into the function. For example, we will say $db is our database connection and you would just modify the two lines of code below:

```
  //original code to change
  function  myFunction() {
  //change to
  function  myFunction($db) {

  //original code to change
  $get_results = myFunction();
  //change to
  $get_results = myFunction($db);
```