# PHP: Should I pass in and return these variables?

Tags: php, function, oop, refactoring, abstraction

I'm currently working on converting my WIP PHP application to an object oriented architecture, as I've found that for my current project good OOP practices are likely to make it much easier. While refactoring my code a bit I came upon a question that is somewhat elementary, but alas I'm not sure of the answer.

I have a section (aka the 'snippet') of code--the code contained in the "GenerateDBSetObjects()" function of the first code sample--that I feel should be put into a function (ie. somewhat like a subroutine), as outlined in the first sample. I want to put it into a separate function block for two reasons:

1. Simplify the main code body
2. Create a function that can be unit tested

However, this creates a problem. Because my program effectively has two large scope variables, so I would need to return two values at once (which is no big deal, as it is a common topic: [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554375/how-should-i-return-multiple-variables-in-a-function-for-best-practises)). The question that I have though is: Since I am restructuring my code in an Object-Oriented fashion, might there be a more efficient way to do this? Something maybe that I haven't considered? Or is it just best to simply pass in and return the variables?

Because $NumDBSets and $DBSets[] are basically global scope not really sure what I should do here.

**index.php**

*After*

```
//-------------------------Primary Vars---------------------------------------//
//Fills $ini with a multi-dimensional, associative array that contains all of the
// parameters listed in DBSearchConfig.ini
$ini = (parse_ini_file("config/DBSearchConfig.ini", true)) 
        or die ("Config file: 'DBSearchCongif.ini' could not be read or found in the config folder. Please contact the system administrator");
$LogFile = $ini['SystemVars']['LogFile']; //Assign $LogFile to the location of the system's specific log file found in the .ini
$NumDBSets = 0;//An integer which stores the number of Database sets used by the program.
$DBSets = array(); //Creates an empty array that will store each of the DatabaseSet Objects. Each of the
//Database Sets holds an array of SQL database connection parameters (ie.
//Hostname, Username, etc.), as well as an array of links to the SQL databases within the dataset, et. al.
//For more info see 'DatabaseSet.php'

$CurrDBSetNum = $ini['SystemVars']['DefaultDBSet']; //Get the current DBSet Number from config.
$CurrentConnectionManager = new ConnectionManager;

GenerateDBSetObjects($DBSets, $NumDBSets);




//-------------------------FUNCTIONS----------------------------------------//

function GenerateDBSetObjects(){
    //Create, Fill and Assign DatabaseSet Objects. Figure out the number of Database sets.
    array_push($DBSets, new DatabaseSet);//Push an empty DatabaseSet object into the list to occupy the '0' index!!!
    foreach($ini['Databases'] as $ConnectInfoList){
        $NumDBSets ++;
        //Create a new DatabaseSet Object for this DB Set!!
        $newDBSetObject = new DatabaseSet;
        $newDBSetObject->ConnectionInfoList = $ConnectInfoList;
        $newDBSetObject->CalculateDBSetFields();
        array_push($DBSets, $newDBSetObject);

    }
}
```

**VS.**

*Before*

```
//-------------------------Primary Vars---------------------------------------//
//Fills $ini with a multi-dimensional, associative array that contains all of the
// parameters listed in DBSearchConfig.ini
$ini = (parse_ini_file("config/DBSearchConfig.ini", true)) 
        or die ("Config file: 'DBSearchCongif.ini' could not be read or found in the config folder. Please contact the system administrator");
$LogFile = $ini['SystemVars']['LogFile']; //Assign $LogFile to the location of the system's specific log file found in the .ini
$NumDBSets = 0;//An integer which stores the number of Database sets used by the program.
$DBSets = array(); //Creates an empty array that will store each of the DatabaseSet Objects. Each of the
//Database Sets holds an array of SQL database connection parameters (ie.
//Hostname, Username, etc.), as well as an array of links to the SQL databases within the dataset, et. al.
//For more info see 'DatabaseSet.php'

$CurrDBSetNum = $ini['SystemVars']['DefaultDBSet']; //Get the current DBSet Number from config.
$CurrentConnectionManager = new ConnectionManager;

//Create, Fill and Assign DatabaseSet Objects. Figure out the number of Database sets.
array_push($DBSets, new DatabaseSet);//Push an empty DatabaseSet object into the list to occupy the '0' index!!!
foreach($ini['Databases'] as $ConnectInfoList){
    $NumDBSets ++;
    //Create a new DatabaseSet Object for this DB Set!!
    $newDBSetObject = new DatabaseSet;
    $newDBSetObject->ConnectionInfoList = $ConnectInfoList;
    $newDBSetObject->CalculateDBSetFields();
    array_push($DBSets, $newDBSetObject);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have decided to take an approach with OOP - consider creating a class which will be responsible for generation and storing `DatabaseSet` objects.
If object of `ConnectionManager` class is required for DatabaseSets generation, mark it as dependency injection.
Class `DatabaseSet` should be declared in separate file: `DatabaseSet.php`.
Let's call our crucial class `DatabaseSetAdapter`:

```
require_once("DatabaseSet.php");

class DatabaseSetAdapter
{
    private $config;
    private $logFile;
    private $NumDBSets = 0;
    private $DBSets = [];
    private $connManager;
    private $currDBSetNum;

    public function __construct($iniFilePath, ConnectionManager $manager)
    {
        $this->config = (parse_ini_file($iniFilePath, true)) 
        or die ("Config file: 'DBSearchCongif.ini' could not be read or found in the config folder. Please contact the system administrator");

        $this->logFile = $this->config['SystemVars']['LogFile'];
        $this->connManager = $manager;
        $this->currDBSetNum = $this->config['SystemVars']['DefaultDBSet'];
    }

    public function generateDBSetObjects()
    {
        //Create, Fill and Assign DatabaseSet Objects. Figure out the number of Database sets.
        $this->DBSets[] = new DatabaseSet;  //Push an empty DatabaseSet object into the list to occupy the '0' index!!!
        foreach($this->config['Databases'] as $connectInfoList){

            //Create a new DatabaseSet Object for this DB Set!!
            $newDBSetObject = new DatabaseSet;
            $newDBSetObject->ConnectionInfoList = $connectInfoList;
            $newDBSetObject->CalculateDBSetFields();
            $this->DBSets[] = $newDBSetObject;
            $this->NumDBSets++;
        }
    }

    public function getNumDBSets()   // a privileged method
    {
        return $this->NumDBSets;
    }    

}

// using of DatabaseSetAdapter:
$dbsetAdapter = new DatabaseSetAdapter("config/DBSearchConfig.ini", new ConnectionManager);
$dbsetAdapter->generateDBSetObjects();
$numDbSets = $dbsetAdapter->getNumDBSets();
....
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It took me a decent bit of reading and thinking to understand what you were saying. I had no clue what you meant by dependency injection (likely due to my lack of formal training). For those people in a similar situation with regards to Dependency Injection, this may help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Comment: @BrandonSnider, you're welcome! It's good to hear that you have learnt something about dependency injection and OOP in PHP

Comment: In response to my previous comment, for those of you looking at dependency injection, or struggling at this like I have:  It helps a ton to be familiar with the SOLID principles of class design, and principles of packaging, "Principles of OOD" on [butunclebob.com](http://butunclebob.com/) seems to be a good resource. This isn't a terrible resource either, but it's targeted more specifically toward C#/.net devs : [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22769/Introduction-to-Object-Oriented-Programming-Concep#identify)

Answer (score 1):

Global scope and OOP don't fit toghether.

You should have an object keeping this info

```
class DBSets {
  private $num;
  private $data;

  function __construct() {
    $this->num = 0;
    $this->data = [];
  }

  //setters and getters for accessing private properties
}
```

If $num only stores the count of elements in $data, then you can remove it and use

```
count($this->data);
```

Comment: You might want to look into Singleton for keeping it unique or make everything static

Comment: Thanks Mihai, The question I have is: is this appropriate? It feels like the DBSets class is simply a datastorage class that holds data. Which I've read is not really the best thing to do (keep in mind my  experience is slightly limited). I think a singleton class makes sense, but wouldn't It be better to call the singleton  something other than DBSets? In the context of my program, a DatabaseSet (aka DBSet) class already exists. And these variables are really just to keep track of these objects and the number of them. I'll consider this though as it is a valid option.

Comment: The names are just as an example. You should name them however you want. And objects are made for storing data and methods for manipulating this data.

Comment: Someone please let me know if I understand this correctly: So, in an OO context, I should NEVER have variables declared in any local or global scope that is not inside of a class definition. Likewise, I should never create and initialize variables in main() (C++) or index.php (where my main code is in PHP). Am I understanding this correctly?